# Analytical expression for $ \int_0^b \frac{(a+x)^k - a^k}{x}dx $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Can an analytical expression be found for the following definite integral:

$$ \int_0^b \frac{(a+x)^k - a^k}{x}dx $$

I have tried in Wolfram Alpha. Unfortunately, it ran out of free calculation time...

In my particular application, I am faced with the following constraints on the various terms:

$$ a,b \in [0,1] \,\, \text{ and } \,\, a = 1-b \,\, \text{ and } \,\, k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

It is possible to get the solution using a discrete sum (using the binomial theorem) or using a recursion. However, we are looking for closed-form expressions without sums or integrals. Not sure it is possible...any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can use binomial theorem..

Comment: Hi @infinity_hunter, you are right. Unfortunately, in doing so you end up either with a discrete sum or a recursion. In my application, we need to avoid that... ! Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @BMBE Do you have any reason to believe that a closed form not involving sums or integrals exists? I'm not saying it doesn't exist, it's just atm I can't think of finding an alternative closed form solution.

Comment: @A-Level Student, I hope that it exists :p It is just that in my application, I need to find a "final" closed formula that does not present any integrals or sums... you can consider this as a constraint on the solution... Indeed, if it exists, it is quite of a challenge... hence I asked the question :)

Comment: Any solution you want is going to be equivalent to the finite sum, so I'm not sure what your goal is here. You can define a new function and call it that sum, but it's the sum all the same. Any other way it's written is just a repackaging..

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}f(x)
=&(a+x)^k-a^k\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^k{k\choose n}a^{k-n}x^n-a^k\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^k{k\choose n}a^{k-n}x^n
\end{align}$$

---

$$\frac{f(x)}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^k{k\choose n}a^{k-n}x^{n-1}$$

---

$$\begin{align}\int_0^b\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm dx
=&\int_0^b\sum_{n=1}^k{k\choose n}a^{k-n}x^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^k{k\choose n}a^{k-n}\int_0^bx^{n-1}\,\mathrm dx\\
=&\sum_{n=1}^k{k\choose n}a^{k-n}\frac{b^n}{n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: @A-LevelStudent The question is an integral, I don't think that is possible

Comment: Sorry, when I said the answer shouldn't include integrals I meant the final solution, not the working necessary in getting to the answer :) See the final paragraph that the OP wrote.

Comment: @A-Level Student, thanks for your comments and inputs! It is exactly that :)

Comment: I am writing another answer atm

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER AND OBSERVATION**

This is not a complete solution; indeed currently I see no way of arriving at a solution that doesn't involve sums, but it's too long for the comments so I'm leaving it as an answer.

However, I have noticed something that may be of use to someone else attempting to answer this questions.

From using the binomial theorem, we arrive at the fact that the integral is equivalent to
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\binom{k}{n}\frac{1}{n}(1-a)^na^{k-n}.$$
It occurred to me that this looks very much like the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\binom{k}{n}(1-a)^na^{k-n}$$ which *does* have a closed form; it is equal to $1-a^k$.

If anyone can see a way of using this result I will be very interested, and very pleased :)

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^b \frac{(a+x)^k - a^k}{x}dx
&=\int_0^b (\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i(a+x)^{k-i-1})dx\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i\int_0^b (a+x)^{k-i-1}dx\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i\dfrac{(a+x)^{k-i}}{k-i}|_0^b\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i\dfrac{(a+b)^{k-i}-a^{k-i}}{k-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} a^i\dfrac{1-a^{k-i}}{k-i}
\qquad a+b=1\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^i-a^k}{k-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^i}{k-i}-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} \dfrac{a^k}{k-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{a^{k-i}}{i}-a^k\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac1{i}\\
&=a^k\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{a^{-i}}{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac1{i}\right)\\
&=a^k\sum_{i=1}^{k} \dfrac{a^{-i}-1}{i}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: I think the OP didn't want the answer to include sums.

Comment: $\sum_i\frac1i$ can be represented as $H_k$ as it is the harmonic sum, the other looks like the taylor series of $\ln(1-a)$

Comment: The only way to not have a sum is, as the other answer does, to give the sum a name and use the name.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to write another answer as the other would be very long. You can use the Incomplete Beta function to define it too. Let's split it into two integrals:
$$I_1=\int_0^b\frac{(a+x)^k}{x}\,dx$$
with $u=ax$ we get $du=dx/a$ so:
$$\frac1a\int_0^{ab}\frac{a^k(1+u)^k}{u/a}\,du=a^k\int_0^{ab}\frac{(1+u)^k}{u}\,du$$
now let $u=v-1$ so $du=dv$ and we get:
$$a^k\int_1^{{1+ab}}\frac{v^k}{(v-1)}\,dv=-a^k\int_1^{1+ab}v^k(1-v)^{-1}\,dv$$
Now remember that the incomplete Beta function is defined as:
$$B(x;\alpha,\beta)=\int_0^xt^{\alpha-1}(1-t)^{\beta-1}\,dt$$

---

as for the second integral, you just have:
$$-a^k\int_0^b\frac1x\,dx$$
which should be fairly easy

Comment: also a side comment: splitting the first integral up into two will give you a beta function $(0,1)$ and an incomplete $(0,1+ab)$

Comment: You can't split the integral this way, as you get two integrals that are not onvergent separately.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński put the lower bound as $\varepsilon$ then use CPV

Comment: Then in the result you get a limit $\epsilon\to 0$ which is not so easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $x=a(y-1)$ and using $a+b=1$ your integral is equal to
$$ I(a) = a^k \int_1^{\frac{1}{a}} \frac{y^k-1}{y-1}dy = a^k J_k(a^{-1})$$
where $$ J_k(z) = \int_1^{z} \frac{y^k-1}{y-1}dy $$
While we need it for $z>1$, it's easier to express it for $z<1$ and then define it for $z>1$ as the analytic continuation. For $z<1$ we have
\begin{align} J_k(z) &= -\int_z^1 \frac{1-y^k}{1-y}dy = \\ &= -\int_0^1 \frac{1-y^k}{1-y}dy + \int_0^z \frac{1}{1-y}dy - \int_0^z \frac{y^k}{1-y}dy = \\
&= -\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} y^k dy - \ln(1-z) - \int_0^z y^k (1-y)^{-1} dy = \\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} \frac{1}{k+1} - \ln(1-z) - B(z;k+1,0) = \\
&= -H_k - \ln(1-z) - B(z;k+1,0)\end{align}
where $H_k$ are the harmonic numbers and $B(z;k+1,0)$ is the incomplete beta function. While he beta function has a logarithmic singularity for $z\to 1$, it is cancelled by $-\ln(1-z)$ and the whole function can by extended to $z>1$.